# Embedded iframe not expanding

Tags: css, iframe

I'm trying to embed a page so that I can have a navbar showing on the side

I've tried the other solutions recommended by stackoverflow (height 100%, flex grow, etc) targeting the iframe but it just won't grow and fill up the remaining space! I'm not sure why this is happening and when I inspect the element through the console all of the elements seem to be applied

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin-right: 232px;
  }
}
.navbar.fixed-right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.fixed-right {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 232px;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-collapse {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.fixed-right {
    left: auto;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-toggle:after {
    border-top: 0.3em solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: 0.3em solid transparent;
    border-right: 0.3em solid;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  .navbar.fixed-right .navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Bootstrap Navbar Sidebar - Fixed to Left or Right</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          id="theme_link"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/materia/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar-fixed-right.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar-fixed-left.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs.css">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="docs.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href>Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Separated link</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">One more separated link</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-class="fixed-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                    Fixed Left
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-class="fixed-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                    Fixed Top
                    <small>(original)</small>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-class="fixed-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    Fixed Right
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- <iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    src="https://petstore.swagger.io/">
</iframe> -->


<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 row flex-grow-1 bg-inf">
    <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" class="flex-grow-1"
    src="https://petstore.swagger.io/">
</iframe>
   </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also noticed a weird gap between the navbar and the iframe. The problem is when I inspect there's no margin or padding inbetween them. How do you go about figuring out and fixing issues like this?

Comment: regarding your `weird gap` : You put a padding-top of 90px on body. That's the issue. I found this out by using the dev tools. So to answer this question: check styles on all parent elements if you find something like this.

Comment: @cloned I see - sorry I missed that because "-top" threw me off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the iframe in your site without any container. This should give you the desired output. 
Just like this:

```
    <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" class="flex-grow-1"
    src="https://petstore.swagger.io/" style="width: 100%; height: 50px"></iframe>
```

No container or anything. Gives you 100% width.

You can set any height you want on the iframe itself. You want it to be 100 of viewport height? then set height: 100vh; Or maybe use something like `height: calc(100vh - 90px)` Whatever you need.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me the container still isn't taking up the whole height on chrome.

Comment: expanded on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with your iframe. Issue lies with the container which you are using above it.

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 row flex-grow-1 bg-inf">

</div>
```

This container is having the max-width of 540px which is causing the problem.

```
@media (min-width: 576px){
    .container {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
}
```

Remove container from iframe will fix the problem.

Hope is answers your query.